# SpringMVC Map Servlet to Root without Removing Content Servlet

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jboss

Currently, we have "root" (`/`) mapped to a static index.html page, but we want to upgrade to a jsp to have dynamic content. Trying to figure out how to do this. We have content that is mapped to the default content server (e.g. `/css`), so we don't want to change too much.

We tried:

- Changing the `.html` to `.jsp`. This resulted in a blank page.
- Changing the `.html` to `.jsp` and then moving the file into the WEB-INF directory. This resulted in a 404.
- Trying to subclass the `DefaultServlet` class that `content` servlet is currently mapped to. This through a 500, with a class assertion error (it checked to see if it was the same class).
- Adding another servlet to that url, but it overwrote the current one.

I've searched StackOverflow, but still haven't found an answer that works.

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming your JSP is out of WEB-INF, it should be one place change, web.xml. Make sure your web.xml mappings accept .jsp and make sure spring-servlet handlers are correct.

Comment: What do your view resolver do for '/'?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this is trivial using Spring MVC:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

And in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/your-applicationContext-web.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Is this what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a controller method mapped to / that returns a view name, which is your jsp file. And make sure your view resolver is set up correctly. Any of the spring mac tutorial hellos world programs out there will show how.